# tricky web form - adding placeholder or values

Tags: css, forms

I am working on a little website which has an expanding form in it. I am trying to figure out if its possible, when you click the button which expands the form, whether a default value can appear at that time.

You can see the theme here:
http://themes.premitheme.com/fullscene/

Click on the Magnifying glass top right and you'll see it expand. I want text to appear in the expanded form, not when its condensed. If I put a "placeholder" you see the text in the condensed form and it goes over the magnifying glass icon. Not pretty.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler or end-of-animation callback method (for the animation that expands the textbox) just set the `placeholder` attribute then, and then clear the attribute when/if the search box is un-expanded.

Comment: Dai, awesome, thanks! Any chance you are able to tell where the end of animation is? I'm a relative newbie, and while I understand basic code, still find it a little tricky to trace all these php calls, etc.
Thanks again!

Comment: Dai, awesome, thanks! Any chance you are able to tell where the end of animation is? I'm a relative newbie, and while I understand basic code, still find it a little tricky to trace all these php calls, etc. Thanks again

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea either. I poked through your site's code but I can't see where the search box expansion animation is specified. I suggest you contact the original developer.

Answer (score 0):

The `placeholder` attribute is perfect for your issue.

You need to find this element.

```
<input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" >
```

It should be in search.php ( maybe searchform.php ). Then you want to add your placeholder attribute like this:

```
<input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="your placeholder">
```